# How to design a thread synchronisation in this case

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore, thread-synchronization

My requirement is as follows

1. There is a process with multiple threads.
2. One of the threads (T1), gets triggered by a user event
3. There is a task that needs to be done in a separate thread(T2), which should be spawned by T1
4. Now, T1 should check that the system is not already doing the task in T2. If its not, then it should spawn T2 and then exit. If T2 is still running, then I should just return from T1 by logging an error. I do not want to hold T1 until T2 is complete.
5. T2 will usually take a long time. So in case T1 is triggered before T2 has finished it should just return with an error.
6. The intention is under no circumstance we should have two threads of T2

I am using a mutex and semaphore to do this, but there may be a simpler way.
Here is what i do.

```
Mutex  g_mutex;
Semaphore  g_semaphone;
```

T1:

```
if TryLock(g_mutex) succeeds // this means T2 is not active.
spawn T2
else  // This means T2 is currently doing something
return with an error.
wait (g_sempahore) // I come here only if I have spawned the thread. now i wait for T2 to pick the task
// I am here means T2 has picked the task, and I can exit.
```

T2:

```
Lock(g_mutex)
signal(g_semaphore)
Do the long task
Unlock(g_mutex)
```

And this works fine. But I want to know if there is a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: The easiest way of ensuring only one T2, ever, is to create a T2 at startup, never terminate it and never create another one.

Comment: Well creating T2 at the start is not possible. It needs the inputs provided from T1. Also, T2 is kind of like the worker thread here.

Comment: OK, so it needs inputs from T1. Create it at startup, it waits on some event/sema, T1 assembles input, it signals T2, T2 does the work, it finishes, loops, waits on the event/sema.

Comment: Oh - you could use some 'workingNow' atomic boolean so that T1 can generate your log message if T2 is busy.  Whatever method you use, I cannot see how to avoid the small window where T2 has finished but not quite got around to signaling it yet. I try to avoid such patterns, eg. by queueing up inputs to T2, but I accept that this may not always be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a mutex like this. Mutex locks should be held for the minimum time necessary. In this case, have a boolean flag `t2_running`, which is protected by the mutex. In T1 do:

1. lock `g_mutex`
2. Read `t2_running`
3. If `t2_running` was set, unlock `g_mutex` and exit with error
4. Set `t2_running`
5. Unlock `g_mutex`
6. Populate data for T2
7. Spawn T2
8. Wait for `g_semaphore`
9. Exit with success

T2 can then do:

1. Read the data
2. signal `g_semaphore`
3. Process the data
4. lock `g_mutex`
5. Clear `t2_running`
6. Unlock `g_mutex`
7. exit